# Windows 8.1 Won't Sleep When Idle

Tags: windows-8, standby, windows-8.1, power-options, powercfg

Ever since I upgraded to the Windows 8.1 beta (and even now with the Windows 8.1 RTM), my computer will not idle to sleep.  This wouldn't be that much of a problem since I almost always remember to put it to sleep before walking away.  But sometimes the computer will wake on its own through a scheduled task, and then the computer will stay on until I return to it.  (By the way, I'd rather not disable scheduled tasks from being able to wake the machine.)

The computer is set to sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity.  I have set the Power Option "When sharing media" to "Allow the computer to sleep."  I have deactivated all "wake_armed" devices so that

```
powercfg /devicequery wake_armed
```

returns

```
NONE
```

I have installed all the drivers Windows couldn't automatically detect (of which there was only my "Creative Game Port").  Finally, I have generated a report from

```
powercfg /energy duration 3600
```

Originally, it informed me of a few problems, such as the "When sharing media..." setting.  As I said earlier, I have now set the "When sharing media" setting to "Allow the computer to sleep."  Here is the report, which seems to suggest that I have no further serious problems:

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3D3292D8A7DEC2F4!17449&authkey=!AIllZ4c3A8_-XHU

SkyDrive will probably show the HTML upon clicking above.  Try clicking Download and then opening the file.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am also having this problem but the solution below did not work. Should I start a new question or somehow add that here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was to leave the Homegroup (which I wasn't using anyway)!  I started a thread in the Neowin.net Forums, and thanks to Kool Box for figuring it out:

http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1176793-windows-81-wont-sleep-when-idle/

Comment: That worked for me too.  Wonder why that prevents sleeping?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I did not have Homegroup activated at all.

The solution that worked for me was to turn off `Play a slide show on the lock screen` in the `Lock Screen` settings:

[image]

Comment: This setting was off by default for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was he "S4 sleep mode" in american megatrend Bios. After disabling the S4 mode, windows 8.1 could successfully sleep after remaining idle.

Answer (score 0):

See here, I figured it out finally for my issues:
[Win 8.1 not going to sleep](https://superuser.com/questions/1031593/win-8-1-not-going-to-sleep)

I used an option (`/WAKETIMERS`) which I had not seen too often before on any helping forum, thus I'm posting it here:

```
powercfg /WAKETIMERS
```

-> To see the scheduled tasks. Helped me figure out to disable the Windows regular maintenance, which avoided sleeping completely (and not only waking it up in the night).