# Windows 8.1 Hibernation / WOL issues. Last Wake command never works

Tags: windows-8, hibernate, wake-on-lan, power-options, powercfg

I setup Windows 8 and had WOL working without issue. The machine would hibernate according to the Power Plan I setup OR by using the shortcut `%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Hibernate`.

Using the last wake command `powercfg -lastwake` would always produce the last reason for wake noting that it was either WOL or USB device (mouse/keyboard).

I applied the Windows 8.1 update and now I regret it because my machine is a wreck. The last wake command executes and now NEVER lists why it woke, it only ever outputs:

```
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 0
```

To test it I put the machine to hibernation using my shortcut. I wait for it to be hibernating and then send a WOL pack to wake it then check the last wake and it's ALWAYS the same.

Why is that important? Because now no matter what my machine will not hibernate according to the Power Plan OR it random wakes itself up for no reason. Nothing has changed other than applying the 8.1 patch (I guess you could say everything changed then...) so I know it's not my machine config or my network config. So I need to use the last wake command to try to hunt down what is turning on my computer. The only thing connected to the machine is the power and ethernet cable because I RDP in to the machine when I want to use it so I KNOW it isn't a USB device (keyboard or mouse) that is doing it because none is attached.

Now, the 8.1 patch seems to have automatically created and joined a HomeGroup and I found this thread [Windows 8.1 Won't Sleep When Idle](https://superuser.com/questions/642922/windows-8-1-wont-sleep-when-idle) and left the HomeGroup so we'll see if the machine follows the Power Plan settings in the next day or so.

Even if the answer for the Power Plan is the HomeGroup, why does the last wake command no longer work in Windows 8.1?

---

Adding driver dump list. Machine is has an ASUS F2A85-M/CSM Motherboard, AMD A10 5800K processor, 8GB of memory running Windows 8 Pro x64 with the 8.1 patch applied.

```
Module Name  Display Name           Driver Type   Link Date             
============ ====================== ============= ======================
1394ohci     1394 OHCI Compliant Ho Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:14 AM  
3ware        3ware                  Kernel        4/11/2013 6:49:23 PM  
ACPI         Microsoft ACPI Driver  Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:35 AM  
acpiex       Microsoft ACPIEx Drive Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:47 AM  
acpipagr     ACPI Processor Aggrega Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:48 AM  
AcpiPmi      ACPI Power Meter Drive Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:53 AM  
acpitime     ACPI Wake Alarm Driver Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:58 AM  
ADP80XX      ADP80XX                Kernel        7/12/2013 5:47:36 PM  
AFD          Ancillary Function Dri Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:50 AM  
agp440       Intel AGP Bus Filter   Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:35 AM  
ahcache      Application Compatibil Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:54 AM  
ahcix64s     ahcix64s               Kernel        11/17/2011 1:25:45 AM 
Alpham1      Ideazon ZBoard USB Hum Kernel        7/23/2007 3:57:03 AM  
Alpham2      Ideazon ZBoard MM USB  Kernel        3/20/2007 5:51:03 AM  
AmdK8        AMD K8 Processor Drive Kernel        8/22/2013 4:46:34 AM  
amdkmdag     amdkmdag               Kernel        9/10/2013 10:45:14 PM 
amdkmdap     amdkmdap               Kernel        9/10/2013 9:24:43 PM  
AmdPPM       AMD Processor Driver   Kernel        8/22/2013 4:46:34 AM  
amdsata      amdsata                Kernel        7/8/2013 6:54:38 PM   
amdsbs       amdsbs                 Kernel        12/11/2012 4:21:44 PM 
amdxata      amdxata                Kernel        7/8/2013 6:45:00 PM   
AODDriver4.2 AODDriver4.2           Kernel        4/5/2012 5:23:37 AM   
AppID        AppID Driver           Kernel        9/14/2013 7:39:40 AM  
arcsas       Adaptec SAS/SATA-II RA Kernel        7/8/2013 8:50:17 PM   
atapi        IDE Channel            Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:39 AM  
AU8168       AU 8168 NT Driver      Kernel        3/14/2013 5:44:07 AM  
b06bdrv      Broadcom NetXtreme II  Kernel        2/4/2013 2:47:18 PM   
BasicDisplay BasicDisplay           Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:31 AM  
BasicRender  BasicRender            Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:27 AM  
bcmfn2       bcmfn2 Service         Kernel        8/2/2013 7:59:11 PM   
Beep         Beep                   Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:24 AM  
bowser       Browser Support Driver File System   8/22/2013 7:38:38 AM  
BthAvrcpTg   Bluetooth Audio/Video  Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:39 AM  
BthHFEnum    Bluetooth Hands-Free A Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:42 AM  
bthhfhid     Bluetooth Hands-Free C Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:16 AM  
BTHMODEM     Bluetooth Serial Commu Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:44 AM  
cdfs         CD/DVD File System Rea File System   8/22/2013 7:40:15 AM  
cdrom        CD-ROM Driver          Kernel        8/22/2013 4:46:35 AM  
circlass     Consumer IR Devices    Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:25 AM  
CLFS         Common Log (CLFS)      Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:20 AM  
CmBatt       Microsoft ACPI Control Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:43 AM  
CNG          CNG                    Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:09 AM  
CompositeBus Composite Bus Enumerat Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:48 AM  
condrv       Console Driver         Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:17 AM  
CSC          Offline Files Driver   Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:00 AM  
dam          Desktop Activity Moder Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:46 AM  
Dfsc         DFS Namespace Client D File System   8/22/2013 7:38:00 AM  
disk         Disk Driver            Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:47 AM  
dmvsc        dmvsc                  Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:14 AM  
drmkaud      Microsoft Trusted Audi Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:24 AM  
DXGKrnl      LDDM Graphics Subsyste Kernel        10/3/2013 7:52:38 AM  
ebdrv        Broadcom NetXtreme II  Kernel        4/8/2013 10:30:03 AM  
EhStorClass  Enhanced Storage Filte Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:15 AM  
EhStorTcgDrv Microsoft driver for s Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:30 AM  
ElbyCDIO     ElbyCDIO Driver        Kernel        3/4/2013 4:21:51 AM   
ErrDev       Microsoft Hardware Err Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:45 AM  
exfat        exFAT File System Driv File System   8/22/2013 7:40:18 AM  
Ext2Fsd      Linux ext2 file system Kernel        7/8/2011 1:08:38 PM   
fastfat      FAT12/16/32 File Syste File System   8/22/2013 7:40:18 AM  
fdc          Floppy Disk Controller Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:18 AM  
FileInfo     File Information FS Mi File System   8/22/2013 7:38:45 AM  
Filetrace    Filetrace              File System   8/22/2013 7:39:41 AM  
flpydisk     Floppy Disk Driver     Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:18 AM  
FltMgr       FltMgr                 File System   8/22/2013 7:40:18 AM  
FsDepends    File System Dependency File System   8/22/2013 7:39:42 AM  
fvevol       BitLocker Drive Encryp Kernel        9/21/2013 3:58:16 AM  
FxPPM        Power Framework Proces Kernel        8/22/2013 4:46:33 AM  
gagp30kx     Microsoft Generic AGPv Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:36 AM  
gencounter   Microsoft Hyper-V Gene Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:23 AM  
GPIOClx0101  Microsoft GPIO Class E Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:54 AM  
HdAudAddServ Microsoft 1.1 UAA Func Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:19 AM  
HDAudBus     Microsoft UAA Bus Driv Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:37 AM  
HidBatt      HID UPS Battery Driver Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:01 AM  
HidBth       Microsoft Bluetooth HI Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:39 AM  
hidi2c       Microsoft I2C HID Mini Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:28 AM  
HidIr        Microsoft Infrared HID Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:16 AM  
HidUsb       Microsoft HID Class Dr Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:58 AM  
HpSAMD       HpSAMD                 Kernel        3/26/2013 5:36:54 PM  
HTTP         HTTP Service           Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:09 AM  
hwpolicy     Hardware Policy Driver Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:17 AM  
hyperkbd     hyperkbd               Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:49 AM  
HyperVideo   HyperVideo             Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:20 AM  
i8042prt     i8042 Keyboard and PS/ Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:15 AM  
iaLPSSi_GPIO Intel(R) Serial IO GPI Kernel        6/26/2013 10:22:54 AM 
iaLPSSi_I2C  Intel(R) Serial IO I2C Kernel        6/26/2013 10:22:53 AM 
iaStorAV     Intel(R) SATA RAID Con Kernel        7/31/2013 8:00:49 PM  
iaStorV      Intel RAID Controller  Kernel        4/11/2011 2:48:16 PM  
intelide     intelide               Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:03 AM  
intelpep     Intel(R) Power Engine  Kernel        9/19/2013 3:12:46 AM  
intelppm     Intel Processor Driver Kernel        8/22/2013 4:46:35 AM  
IpFilterDriv IP Traffic Filter Driv Kernel        8/22/2013 7:35:50 AM  
IPMIDRV      IPMIDRV                Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:56 AM  
IPNAT        IP Network Address Tra Kernel        9/14/2013 7:38:22 AM  
IRENUM       IR Bus Enumerator      Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:30 AM  
isapnp       isapnp                 Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:20 AM  
iScsiPrt     iScsiPort Driver       Kernel        8/22/2013 7:35:40 AM  
kbdclass     Keyboard Class Driver  Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:23 AM  
kbdhid       Keyboard HID Driver    Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:13 AM  
kbldfltr     kbldfltr               Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:37 AM  
kdnic        Microsoft Kernel Debug Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:26 AM  
KSecDD       KSecDD                 Kernel        9/21/2013 3:59:44 AM  
KSecPkg      KSecPkg                Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:32 AM  
ksthunk      Kernel Streaming Thunk Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:31 AM  
lltdio       Link-Layer Topology Di Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:18 AM  
LSI_SAS      LSI_SAS                Kernel        3/28/2013 1:42:34 PM  
LSI_SAS2     LSI_SAS2               Kernel        3/28/2013 1:45:05 PM  
LSI_SAS3     LSI_SAS3               Kernel        3/15/2013 7:38:40 PM  
LSI_SSS      LSI_SSS                Kernel        3/15/2013 7:39:38 PM  
luafv        UAC File Virtualizatio File System   8/22/2013 7:39:36 AM  
megasas      megasas                Kernel        7/23/2013 5:08:29 PM  
megasr       megasr                 Kernel        6/3/2013 6:02:39 PM   
Modem        Modem                  Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:15 AM  
monitor      Microsoft Monitor Clas Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:37 AM  
mouclass     Mouse Class Driver     Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:13 AM  
mouhid       Mouse HID Driver       Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:13 AM  
mountmgr     Mount Point Manager    Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:04 AM  
mpsdrv       Windows Firewall Autho Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:06 AM  
MRxDAV       WebDav Client Redirect File System   8/22/2013 7:37:19 AM  
mrxsmb       SMB MiniRedirector Wra File System   9/21/2013 3:56:34 AM  
mrxsmb10     SMB 1.x MiniRedirector File System   8/22/2013 7:35:42 AM  
mrxsmb20     SMB 2.0 MiniRedirector File System   9/21/2013 3:57:59 AM  
MsBridge     Microsoft MAC Bridge   Kernel        8/22/2013 7:35:50 AM  
Msfs         Msfs                   File System   8/22/2013 7:40:24 AM  
msgpiowin32  Common Driver for Butt Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:08 AM  
mshidkmdf    Pass-through HID to KM Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:06 AM  
mshidumdf    Pass-through HID to UM Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:06 AM  
msisadrv     msisadrv               Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:03 AM  
MSKSSRV      Microsoft Streaming Se Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:31 AM  
MSPCLOCK     Microsoft Streaming Cl Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:30 AM  
MSPQM        Microsoft Streaming Qu Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:31 AM  
MsRPC        MsRPC                  Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:22 AM  
mssmbios     Microsoft System Manag Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:41 AM  
MSTEE        Microsoft Streaming Te Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:38 AM  
MTConfig     Microsoft Input Config Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:36 AM  
Mup          Mup                    File System   8/22/2013 7:40:28 AM  
mvumis       mvumis                 Kernel        3/20/2013 1:14:53 PM  
NativeWifiP  NativeWiFi Filter      Kernel        9/11/2013 5:31:37 AM  
NDIS         NDIS System Driver     Kernel        9/21/2013 3:59:30 AM  
NdisCap      Microsoft NDIS Capture Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:06 AM  
NdisImPlatfo Microsoft Network Adap Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:17 AM  
NdisTapi     Remote Access NDIS TAP Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:16 AM  
Ndisuio      NDIS Usermode I/O Prot Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:34 AM  
NdisVirtualB Microsoft Virtual Netw Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:25 AM  
NdisWan      Remote Access NDIS WAN Kernel        8/22/2013 7:35:55 AM  
NdisWanLegac Remote Access LEGACY N Kernel        8/22/2013 7:35:55 AM  
NDProxy      NDIS Proxy             Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:15 AM  
Ndu          Windows Network Data U Kernel        8/22/2013 7:35:42 AM  
NetBIOS      NetBIOS Interface      File System   8/22/2013 7:38:58 AM  
NetBT        NetBT                  Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:01 AM  
netvsc       netvsc                 Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:43 AM  
Npfs         Npfs                   File System   8/22/2013 7:40:25 AM  
npsvctrig    Named pipe service tri Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:22 AM  
nsiproxy     NSI Proxy Service Driv Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:34 AM  
Ntfs         Ntfs                   File System   8/22/2013 4:48:02 AM  
Null         Null                   Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:24 AM  
nvraid       nvraid                 Kernel        9/12/2011 8:01:54 PM  
nvstor       nvstor                 Kernel        9/12/2011 7:53:04 PM  
nv_agp       NVIDIA nForce AGP Bus  Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:38 AM  
Parport      Parallel port driver   Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:02 AM  
partmgr      Partition Manager      Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:20 AM  
pci          PCI Bus Driver         Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:31 AM  
pciide       pciide                 Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:03 AM  
pcmcia       pcmcia                 Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:00 AM  
pcw          Performance Counters f Kernel        8/22/2013 4:46:34 AM  
pdc          pdc                    Kernel        9/21/2013 12:28:39 AM 
PEAUTH       PEAUTH                 Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:07 AM  
Processor    Processor Driver       Kernel        8/22/2013 4:46:34 AM  
Psched       QoS Packet Scheduler   Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:06 AM  
PxHlpa64     PxHlpa64               Kernel        10/17/2011 10:29:34 AM
QWAVEdrv     QWAVE driver           Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:27 AM  
RasAcd       Remote Access Auto Con Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:01 AM  
RasPppoe     Remote Access PPPOE Dr Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:37 AM  
rdbss        Redirected Buffering S File System   8/22/2013 7:37:48 AM  
rdpbus       Remote Desktop Device  Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:52 AM  
RDPDR        Remote Desktop Device  Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:46 AM  
RdpVideoMini Remote Desktop Video M Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:52 AM  
rdyboost     ReadyBoost             Kernel        9/24/2013 3:04:38 AM  
ReFS         ReFS                   File System   8/22/2013 4:46:38 AM  
RsFx0151     RsFx0151 Driver        File System   6/17/2011 4:28:58 AM  
rspndr       Link-Layer Topology Di Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:34 AM  
s3cap        s3cap                  Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:37 AM  
sbp2port     SBP-2 Transport/Protoc Kernel        8/22/2013 4:46:34 AM  
scfilter     Smart card PnP Class F Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:07 AM  
sdbus        sdbus                  Kernel        9/21/2013 3:59:26 AM  
sdstor       SD Storage Port Driver Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:32 AM  
secdrv       Security Driver        Kernel        9/13/2006 9:18:38 AM  
SensorsSimul UMDF Reflector service Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:50 AM  
SerCx        Serial UART Support Li Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:02 AM  
SerCx2       Serial UART Support Li Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:37 AM  
Serenum      Serenum Filter Driver  Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:17 AM  
Serial       Serial port driver     Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:08 AM  
sermouse     Serial Mouse Driver    Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:02 AM  
sfloppy      High-Capacity Floppy D Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:00 AM  
SiSRaid2     SiSRaid2               Kernel        9/24/2008 2:28:20 PM  
SiSRaid4     SiSRaid4               Kernel        10/1/2008 5:56:04 PM  
spaceport    Storage Spaces Driver  Kernel        9/11/2013 5:33:58 AM  
SpbCx        Simple Peripheral Bus  Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:00 AM  
srv          Server SMB 1.xxx Drive File System   8/22/2013 7:37:14 AM  
srv2         Server SMB 2.xxx Drive File System   9/21/2013 3:58:17 AM  
srvnet       srvnet                 File System   9/11/2013 5:31:45 AM  
stexstor     stexstor               Kernel        11/26/2012 7:02:51 PM 
storahci     Microsoft Standard SAT Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:39 AM  
storflt      Hyper-V Storage Accele Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:06 AM  
stornvme     Microsoft Standard NVM Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:39 AM  
storvsc      storvsc                Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:34 AM  
storvsp      storvsp                Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:32 AM  
swenum       Software Bus Driver    Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:29 AM  
Tcpip        TCP/IP Protocol Driver Kernel        9/21/2013 3:59:49 AM  
TCPIP6       Microsoft IPv6 Protoco Kernel        9/21/2013 3:59:49 AM  
tcpipreg     TCP/IP Registry Compat Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:03 AM  
tdx          NetIO Legacy TDI Suppo Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:34 AM  
terminpt     Microsoft Remote Deskt Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:16 AM  
TPM          TPM                    Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:21 AM  
TsUsbFlt     TsUsbFlt               Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:28 AM  
TsUsbGD      Remote Desktop Generic Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:46 AM  
tunnel       Microsoft Tunnel Minip Kernel        8/22/2013 7:35:45 AM  
uagp35       Microsoft AGPv3.5 Filt Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:38 AM  
UASPStor     USB Attached SCSI (UAS Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:58 AM  
UCX01000     USB Controller Extensi Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:32 AM  
udfs         udfs                   File System   8/22/2013 7:40:19 AM  
UEFI         Microsoft UEFI Driver  Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:03 AM  
uliagpkx     Uli AGP Bus Filter     Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:38 AM  
umbus        UMBus Enumerator Drive Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:59 AM  
UmPass       Microsoft UMPass Drive Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:58 AM  
usbccgp      Microsoft USB Generic  Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:04 AM  
usbcir       eHome Infrared Receive Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:26 AM  
usbehci      Microsoft USB 2.0 Enha Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:15 AM  
usbfilter    AMD USB Filter Driver  Kernel        8/28/2012 9:27:12 PM  
usbhub       Microsoft USB Standard Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:33 AM  
USBHUB3      SuperSpeed Hub         Kernel        9/17/2013 3:01:13 AM  
usbohci      Microsoft USB Open Hos Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:27 AM  
usbprint     Microsoft USB PRINTER  Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:32 AM  
USBSTOR      USB Mass Storage Drive Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:15 AM  
usbuhci      Microsoft USB Universa Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:28 AM  
USBXHCI      USB xHCI Compliant Hos Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:19 AM  
VClone       VClone                 Kernel        3/10/2013 8:49:12 PM  
vdrvroot     Microsoft Virtual Driv Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:49 AM  
VerifierExt  VerifierExt            Kernel        9/14/2013 7:40:56 AM  
vhdmp        vhdmp                  Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:05 AM  
viaide       viaide                 Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:03 AM  
Vid          Vid                    Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:02 AM  
vmbus        Virtual Machine Bus    Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:39 AM  
VMBusHID     VMBusHID               Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:50 AM  
vmbusr       Virtual Machine Bus Pr Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:45 AM  
volmgr       Volume Manager Driver  Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:53 AM  
volmgrx      Dynamic Volume Manager Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:23 AM  
volsnap      Storage volumes        Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:46 AM  
vpci         Microsoft Hyper-V Virt Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:59 AM  
vpcivsp      Microsoft Hyper-V PCI  Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:50 AM  
vsmraid      vsmraid                Kernel        1/23/2013 3:35:43 PM  
VSPerfDrv110 Performance Tools Driv Kernel        7/1/2012 11:25:47 PM  
VSTXRAID     VIA StorX Storage RAID Kernel        1/21/2013 2:00:28 PM  
vwifibus     Virtual WiFi Bus Drive Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:00 AM  
WacomPen     Wacom Serial Pen HID D Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:15 AM  
WdBoot       Windows Defender Boot  Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:24 AM  
Wdf01000     Kernel Mode Driver Fra Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:56 AM  
WdFilter     Windows Defender Mini- File System   8/22/2013 7:39:34 AM  
WdNisDrv     Windows Defender Netwo Kernel        8/22/2013 7:35:32 AM  
WFPLWFS      Microsoft Windows Filt Kernel        9/21/2013 3:56:27 AM  
WIMMount     WIMMount               File System   8/22/2013 7:39:34 AM  
WmiAcpi      Microsoft Windows Mana Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:04 AM  
wpcfltr      Family Safety Filter D Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:43 AM  
WpdUpFltr    WPD Upper Class Filter Kernel        8/22/2013 7:38:45 AM  
ws2ifsl      Winsock IFS Driver     Kernel        8/22/2013 7:40:03 AM  
WudfPf       User Mode Driver Frame Kernel        8/22/2013 7:37:21 AM  
WUDFRd       Windows Driver Foundat Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:50 AM  
WUDFWpdFs    WUDFWpdFs              Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:50 AM  
WSDScan      WSD Scan Support       Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:50 AM  
WSDPrintDevi WSD Print Support      Kernel        8/22/2013 7:39:58 AM  
WUDFSensorLP UMDF Reflector service Kernel        8/22/2013 7:36:50 AM
```

Comment: Hibernation supports is supported by drivers.  More information about the system and the drivers being used.

Comment: So in Windows 8.1 the drivers stopped reporting in that they woke the system? Forget why the system isn't going to sleep and focus on why the machine makes itself yet has no record of why.

Comment: I didn't say that.  I simply said hibernation is supported by drivers.  I want specific hardware information.

Comment: Does it randomly wake up if you pull the Ethernet cord?  Are you sure the network adapter is currently set to only wake up on the magic packet instead of _any_ traffic?

Comment: If I hibernate the box it does not wake when the Ethernet is unplugged/plugged. Currently, WOL Magic Packet Only is turned on. I have previously used "ANY" traffic without any issues and if the wake was a result of the WOL then the "last wake" command would like my Ethernet adapter as the source.